# Count occurrences in MultiMap

Tags: java, guava, multimap

I have a MultiMap that has multiple similar values:

```
{Entertainment=[5], Food=[2, 2, 2], Products=[11], Health & Beauty=[3]}
```

How do I count the total of these keys so that it counts as follows?

```
Entertainment = 1
Food = 3
Products = 1
Health & Beauty = 1
```

The number inside the array is the category id, so that Food has 3 occurrences.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either `multimap.get(key).size()` or `multimap.keys().count(key)` should work.

[Documentation](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: The problem with this is it loops with all available keys including Food that has size of 3. It also loops 3 times because of this.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about looping over the keys: just loop over the `keySet()` rather than over `keys()` to get each key once only.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your map is declared as follows : `MultiMap<String, Integer> map`, you can do the following :

```
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
    int count = map.get(key).size();
}
```

Comment: It also counts Food as 3 times. In total, it will count 6, instead I want only 4 (Entertainment, Food, Products, Health & Beauty)

Comment: Yeah, this should be `for (String key : map.keySet())` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using `asMap()`, you can get the `Map<String, Collection<Integer>>` representation of the `Multimap`, from which it's easy to get the count directly without multiple lookups:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<Integer>> entry : multimap.asMap().entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue().size());
}
```

Note: to get the `Set` of keys on the `Multimap`, you need to call `keySet()`, *not* `keys()` (which indeeds repeats the key as many times as it has values).